# Replace a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to add a element to a list and replace it with my list.

So i wrote

```
initialstate(0,[],[[1,0],[2,3],[1,2],[1,3]]).
add(X,L2,[X|L2]).
```

I would like to make something like that...

```
?- initialstate(_,List,_),add(4,List,List)
```

and replace me the initialstate to this one

```
initial_state(0,[4],[[1,0],[2,3],[1,2],[1,3]]).
```

The maining question for me it's how to replace the list inside the indetifiers "initialstate".

I am new in prolog...Please help me... and sorry if it is something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once provided the appropriate declaration

```
:- dynamic initialstate/3.
```

you could update your DB in this way

```
?- retract(initialstate(A,B,C)), assertz(initialstate(A,[4|B],C)).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a list you get a different list. So you need a different name for it.

Prolog is not an imperative language but more a descriptive one. This means: you do not say do this and this. You say this is like that and when this is the case this is true/false in files (knowledge). Then you start the interpreter, consult the knowledge and ask questions wether something is true.

Writing A = B means that A is always B.

```
?- initialstate(_,List,_),add(4,List,List)
```

means initialstate of a List is when 4 added to the list is the list itself. 
This is not `true`. if 4 is added there should be a 4 where no 4 was before.

You can do this:

```
append4(List, ListWithFourInside) :- append(List, [4], ListWithFourInside).
```

Which reads like when I append 4 to a list I get a list with 4 inside.

It can be done shorter if you want the 4 in the beginning

```
add4(List, ListWithFourInside) :- [4 | List] = ListWithFourInside.
```

or even shorter:

```
add4(List, [4|List]).
```

Comment: And how i put this ListWithFourInside in my initialstate(_,X,_) at X. Replace the current List with the ListWithFourInside?

Comment: In Prolog you do not replace. Tell me an pure english descriptive sentence only using the verb `is` and I can help you transform what you want to see into prolog.

Comment: When i try to do this at prolog it throws me up this error : 
?- add4(List, [4|List]). 
ERROR: Undefined procedure: add4/2
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         add/3
false.

And i don't know how to replace in my initialstate the list. How to create the same initialstate but with the NewList

Comment: add4 and the other defninitions have to be written to a file. This file is then consulted (= knowledge of the file added) to the prolog-interpreter. `?-` means that you can now ask the interpreter for somthing and it will say yes, no or that it does not understand(error). In your case you did not consult the source file with the definitions.

Comment: From the begging i had create this file. But i haven't write the "add". So i wrote it. I consulted it in prolog. It create the newlist with the element 4 inside but i don't know how to put it inside the initial state. This is the most important for me. Include the newlist inside in my first initialstate. Sorry if my question it's stupid but i am trying to understand the prolog.

Comment: what does initialstate mean? If it works you can type `?- add4([], List).` or `?- add4([], []).` or `?- add4(L, L).`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38928/discussion-between-user-and-nickname)

Comment: See my first question and you will understand what is the initialstate!